# Limiting the times that .split() splits, rather than truncating the resulting array

Tags: javascript, split, query-string

Really, pretty much what the title says.

Say you have this string:

```
var theString = "a=b=c=d";
```

Now, when you run `theString.split("=")` the result is `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` as expected. And, of course, when you run `theString.split("=", 2)` you get `["a", "b"]`, which after reading [the MDN page for `String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) makes sense to me.

However, the behavior I'm looking for is more like Java's `String#split()`: Instead of building the array normally, then returning the first *n* elements, it builds an array of the first *n-1* matches, then adds all the remaining characters as the last element of the array. See [the relevant docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) for a better description.

How can I get this effect in Javascript?

I'm looking for the answer with the best performance that works like the Java implementation, though the actual way it works can be different.

I'd post my attempt, but I don't know how to go about writing this at all.

Comment: I thought there might be a very simple one line es6 code to implement this?

Comment: This feature, I miss from Visual Basic very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the exact equivalent of the Java implementation (no error checking or guard clauses etc):

```
function split(str, sep, n) {
    var out = [];

    while(n--) out.push(str.slice(sep.lastIndex, sep.exec(str).index));

    out.push(str.slice(sep.lastIndex));
    return out;
}

console.log(split("a=b=c=d", /=/g, 2)); // ['a', 'b', 'c=d']
```

This has the added benefit of not computing the complete split beforehand, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Could you add a quick explanation of how this works?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I iterate "limit" number of times, and on each iteration I use a stateful regex to find the next occurrence of the splitting character. The regex remembers where its last match was, and once it executes I know where the next match is. I add the string slice between those two locations on each iteration. Outside the loop, I add the string slice between the last regex match and the end of the string.

Comment: And since the OP asked about performance - this implementation is about twice as fast (in Chrome) as the other two. Surprised me!

Comment: @SMcCrohan That is indeed surprising. I was sure this would perform better as the string and number of splits became asymptotically larger, but I was assuming the constant overhead in the JS regex would make it slower than the others for small input.

Comment: @Asad - Yes, that was for a test with a large number of separators in the string. With very short input strings, it fell behind the substring approach, but not by much - 14%.

Comment: @SMcCrohan As it happens, I'm mostly splitting strings with lots of separators, so this will be fastest for me. Many thanks for the performance testing.

Comment: If the user passes in a separator without the global flag, this will break. Also, `sep.exec(str)` can return null. Checks for each of these (you can check if the separator is global with `sep.global`) should be considered.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29998501/1736092) from Asad is excellent as it allows for variable length RegExp separators (e.g. `/\s+/g`, splitting along any length of whitespace, including newlines). However, there are a couple issues with it.

1. If the separator does not use the global flag, it will break.
2. The `exec` can return `null` and cause it to break. This can happen if the separator does not appear in the input string.
3. If the limit is larger than the separation points, you end up looping back over the string with likely unintended results.
4. The limit is required, so no easy way to find the maximum splits.

The following addresses these issues while being just as performant:

```js
/**
 * Split a string with a RegExp separator an optionally limited number of times.
 * @param {string} input
 * @param {RegExp} separator
 * @param {number} [limit] - If not included, splits the maximum times
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function split(input, separator, limit) {
  // Ensure the separator is global
  separator = new RegExp(separator, 'g');
  // Allow the limit argument to be excluded
  limit = limit ?? -1;

  const output = [];
  let finalIndex = 0;

  while (limit--) {
    const lastIndex = separator.lastIndex;
    const search = separator.exec(input);
    if (search === null) {
        break;
    }
    finalIndex = separator.lastIndex;
    output.push(input.slice(lastIndex, search.index));
  }

  output.push(input.slice(finalIndex));

  return output;
}
```

```js
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/, 3)
// ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/, 2)
// ["foo", "bar", "baz quux"]
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/, 1)
// ["foo", "bar baz quux"]
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/, 0)
// ["foo bar baz quux"]

// A higher limit than possible splits
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/, 4)
// ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]

// A split that doesn't exist
split("foo bar baz quux", /p/, 2)
// ["foo bar baz quux"]

// Not providing a limit finds the maximum splits
split("foo bar baz quux", /\s+/)
// ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]
```

Notes:

In production code, it's recommended not to mutate function arguments. Both `separator` and `limit` are being mutated. You can choose to create new variables at the top of the function to avoid this if desired. I chose not to do this to keep the example code short. This is not production code.

I did not include any defensive code to check the function argument types. This would be a good thing to consider for production code, or consider TypeScript ;)

Originally I threw an `Error` if the provided separator did not have the global flag set. See the comments below for reasons why it might be desired to add the global flag for the user instead of throwing. Thank you for the suggestion @Stephen P.

Comment: Good catch, i didn't think about those.

Comment: Rather than require the caller to remember to use the global flag, and throw an error if they don't, you can create another RegExp from theirs: `const splitter = new RegExp(separator, 'g');` then use `splitter.exec(input)` — no harm if they've already supplied the global flag, and it works more like the regular `string.split(regex)` which doesn't need/want the global flag.

Comment: @StephenP I think that's a great idea

Answer (score 4):

I'd use something like this:

```
function JavaSplit(string,separator,n) {
    var split = string.split(separator);
    if (split.length <= n)
        return split;
    var out = split.slice(0,n-1);
    out.push(split.slice(n-1).join(separator));
    return out;
}
```

What we're doing here is:

1. Splitting the string entirely
2. Taking the first n-1 elements, as described.
3. Re-joining the remaining elements.
4. Appending them to the array from step 2 and returning.

One might reasonably think you could chain all of those calls together, but `.push()` mutates an array rather than returning a new one. It's also a bit easier for you to follow this way.

Comment: hi, maybe you need to check the split result length is bigger than n before doing slice, otherwise just return the split result.

Comment: I like this one for its simplicity, but I'm accepting the other because (as far as I can tell without benchmarking) it's more efficient.

Comment: It is, yes. I was curious just how much so, so I ran a quick jsperf - was about a 25% difference.

Comment: This assumes the separator is fixed length. Using something like `string.split(/\s+/);` will cause this to break.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const theString = "a=b=c=d";
const [first, ...rest] = theString.split("=");
const second = rest.join("=")
console.log(first, second)
```

If you are using ECMA 2015, you just need 2 lines.

Comment: It doesn't work for variable `n`. but for known smaller `n`

Comment: This assumes the separator is fixed length. Using something like `theString.split(/\s+/);` will cause this to break.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I used after reading the top few answers. I wanted to post exactly this answer unti I found yours.

Answer (score 3):

One more possible implementation:

```
function split(s, separator, limit) {
  // split the initial string using limit
  var arr = s.split(separator, limit);
  // get the rest of the string...
  var left = s.substring(arr.join(separator).length + separator.length);
  // and append it to the array
  arr.push(left);
  return arr;
}
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8vq8vzq/1/).

Comment: Though I'm not quite sure about `length + 1` - I guess it depends on your requirements - whether you want to have a leading `separator` in the last element or not.

Comment: Replace `+ 1` with `+separator.length`, in case you get a multicharacter separator.

Comment: This assumes the separator is fixed length. Using something like `s.split(/\s+/, limit);` will cause this to break.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that in less lines and avoiding loops:

```
const theString = "some=string=with=separators";
const limit = 2;
const parts = theString.split('=', limit);
parts.push(theString.slice(parts.join('').length + limit));
```

Comment: This assumes the separator is fixed length. Using something like `theString.split(/\s+/, limit);` will cause this to break.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something closer to PHP's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Here's a method I've devised:

```
String.prototype.explode = function(sep, n) {
  var arr = this.split(sep, n)
  if (arr[n-1] != undefined) arr[n-1] += this.substring(arr.join(' ').length);
  return arr;
}
```

This method splits the string like normal, determines if we've hit our limit, and uses `substring` to append the text beyond our last split (we can directly access the offset of the first character beyond the last split by getting the `length` of a `join` used on the array with any single character as the separator)

This method is used just like `split`:

```
str = 'my/uri/needs/to/be/split';
splitResult = str.split('/', 4);
explodeResult = str.explode('/', 4);
console.log(splitResult);
console.log(explodeResult);

// The following will be written to the console:
// splitResult:   ["my", "uri", "needs", "to"]
// explodeResult: ["my", "uri", "needs", "to/be/split"]
```

And of course, this can be spun as a function too:

```
function explode(str, sep, n) {
  var arr = str.split(sep, n)
  if (arr[n-1] != undefined) arr[n-1] += this.substring(arr.join(' ').length);
  return arr;
}

str = 'my/uri/needs/to/be/split';
explodeResult = explode(str, '/', 4);
```

Comment: Why are you rejoining with a set separator of `' '` instead of the passed in separator? Also, this assumes the separator is fixed length. Using something like `str.split(/\s+/, n);` will cause this to break.

Answer (score 0):

This my implementation:

```js
String.prototype.splitRemainder = function(delim, count) {
 if (typeof delim !== 'string') {
  return this.split();    
 }

 if (typeof count !== 'number') {
  return this.split(delim);
 }

 if (count < 2) {
  return this.split(delim);
 }

 count--;
 const parts = this.split(delim, count);
 const remainder = this.slice(parts.join('').length + count);

 if (remainder.length > 0) {
  parts.push(remainder);
 }

 return parts;
}

console.log("dasd asds asds asdasd asdasdas".splitRemainder(" ", 4));
console.log("hello-to-you-too".splitRemainder("-",2));
```

Note that it is not the most efficient way to implement it. So if you're looking for the most efficient solution this is not it.